# Using home phone cabling as home network

Tags: routing, ethernet, layer1, cable, cabling

I've just moved into a new build apartment.

Each room has a female telephone port (431A?), connected to a female telephone port in my electricity cupboard. My BT telephone line then comes into the same cupboard into another female telephone port, and a phone cable runs between the 2 to route the phone line to the rest of my rooms.

My question is, could I put my ADSL router in the cupboard, connected up to my telephone line, then take an ethernet/rj45 cable out and in to the female telphone port that supplies the rest of the apartment? Using some of these adapters? - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rj45-Socket-Bt-431a-Plug/dp/B0042K50UO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1436194276&sr=8-1&keywords=431A+rj45

If it's possible, would I be able to get cat5e/6 equivalent gigabit speeds?

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for asking; unfortunately this question seems to be about home / consumer networking.  Both home networking and consumer class devices are [off-topic here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask/).  [su] is the right place to ask this question;  rest assured that several of our members answer there too.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Unfortunately, questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Comment: [LRE](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2950-lre-997-switch/prod_qas09186a0080185383.html) - 5 to 15 Mbps at distances of up to 5000 ft (1524 m)

Comment: @RonRoyston, really? A solution that is entirely end of life for 5 years? Not to mention it won't work on a phone feed that is spliced together to cables from multiple rooms as described by the OP.

Comment: @YLearn  https://www.adtran.com/web/page/portal/Adtran/group/4408

Comment: @RonRoyston, that would have been a much better link to utilize in the above comment than an EoL product.  And while that is a current product, from what I can see of the product it still does not appear it would function on cabling where a single pair is spliced together to multiple locations simultaneously.

Comment: @MikePennington I appreciate I may have ended up in the wrong place, but I'm not sure this question is that suited to Super User either. I went to the Stack Exchange list of forums first and this seemed like the most likely place to get an answer. And as the answers I've received would suggest I think this question might belong here. I've edited it to fit in more - does that suit you better?

Comment: @YLearn Please see comment above

Comment: @bbeckford, edit fail... I rolled back

Comment: @bbeckford, just because someone answers an off topic question, doesn't make it on topic. Members of this community are very knowledgeable in many areas and could provide an answer to a wide variety of questions that are off topic here. As for your edit, there are key differences in how typical office phone cabling is run and common practices in residential phone cabling. Explicitly residential phone cabling often splices multiple runs together to one "feed.". Office phone cabling typically provides dedicated runs terminated in some type of punchdown block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The odds of the telephone cabling working are very small.

First, standard telephone cabling is Category-3 that would top out at 10 Mb.  Likely, it only has one or two pairs in the cable, but gigabit requires all four pairs.

Tolerances for anything over 10Base-T are pretty tight, and standard telephone cabling is just not designed for network use above 10 Mb.

Comment: [LRE](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2950-lre-997-switch/prod_qas09186a0080185383.html) - 5 to 15 Mbps at distances of up to 5000 ft (1524 m)

Comment: @Ron Royston, it is very, very doubtful that his ADSL router has such a port on the client side, and even less likely that his client equipment has such port(s). Also, it doesn't meet his requirement for gigabit equivalent speeds.

Comment: in-house DSL is an option for him.  Cisco LRE is EOS but I'm sure there are products out there.  Adtran maybe?  WiFi makes most sense.

Comment: Adtran, as suggested.  First google hit for Adtran LRE.  adtran.com/web/page/portal/Adtran/group/4408  Your welcome.